# Child service data access to other services with Apollo Federation configuration

Tags: apollo-server, apollo-federation

We've been using Apollo Federation for about 1.5 years as our main api. Behind the federation gateway are 6 child graphql services which are all combined at the gateway. This configuration really works excellent when you have a result set of data which spans the different services. E.g. A list of tickets which references the user who purchased and event it is associated with it, etc.

One place we have experienced this breaking down is when a pre-set of data is needed which is already defined in another child service (or across other child services) (resolver/path). There is no way (that has been discovered by us) to query the federation from a child service to get a federated set of data for use by a resolver to work with that data.

For example, say we have a graphql query defined which queries all tickets for an event, and through federation returns the purchaser's data, the event's data and the products data. If I need this data set from a resolver, I would need to make all those queries again myself duplicating dataSource logic and having to match up the data in code.

One crazy thought which came up is to setup [`apollo-datasource-rest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-datasource-rest) dataSource to make queries against our gateway end point as a dataSource for our resolvers. This way we can request the data we need and let Apollo Federation stitch all the data together as it is designed to do. So instead of the resolver querying the database for all the different pieces of data and then matching them up, we would request the data from our graphql gateway where this query is already defined.

What we are trying to avoid by doing this is having a repeated set of queries in child services to get the details which are already available in (or across) other services.

#### The question

Is this a really bad idea?
Is it a plausible idea?
Has anyone tried something like this before?

---

Yes we would have to ensure that there aren't circular dependencies on the resolvers. In our case I see the "dataSource accessing the gateway" utilized in gathering initial data in mutations.

---

Example of a federated query. In this query, `event`, `allocatedTo`, `purchasedBy`, and `product` are all types in other services. `event` is an Event type, `allocatedTo` and `purchasedBy` are a Profile type, and `product` is a Product type. This query provides me with all the data I would use to say, send an email notification to the people in the result set. Though to get this data from a resolver in a mutation to queue up those emails means I need to make many queries and align all the data through code myself instead of using the Gateway/federation which does this already with the already established query. The thought around using [`apollo-datasource-rest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-datasource-rest) to query our own gateway is get at this data in this form. Not through separate queries and code to align id's etc.

```
query getRegisteredUsers($eventId: ID!) {
  communications {
    event(eventId: $eventId) {
      registered {
        event {
          name
        }
        isAllocated,
        hasCheckedIn,
        lastUpdatedAt,
        allocatedTo {
          firstName
          lastName
          email
        }
        purchasedBy {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
        product {
          __typename
          ...on Ticket {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I didn't quite understand the question until I looked at your edits, which had some examples.

> Is this a really bad idea?

In my experience, yes. Not as an idea, as you're in good company with other very smart people who have done this.

> Is it a plausible idea?

Absolutely it's plausible, but I don't recommend it.

> Has anyone tried something like this before?

Yes, but I hope you don't.

---

### Your Question

Having resolvers make requests back to the Gateway:

I do not recommend this. I've seen this happen, and I've personally worked to help companies out of the mess this takes you into. Circular dependencies are going to happen. Latency is just going to skyrocket as you have more and more hops, TLS handshakes, etc. Do orchestration instead. It feels weird to introduce non-GraphQL, but IMO in the end it's way simpler, faster, and more maintainable than where "just talk to the gateway" takes you.

---

### What then?

When you're dealing with some mutations which require data from across multiple data sources to be able to process a single thing (like sending a transaction email to a person), you have some choices. Something that helped me figure this out was the question "how would I have done this before GraphQL?"

1. Orchestration: you have a single "orchestration service", which takes the mutation and makes calls (preferably non-GraphQL, so REST, gRPC, Lambda?) to the owner services to collect the data. The orchestration layer does NOT own data, but it can speak with the other services. It's like Federation, but for sending the data into the request, instead of into the response.
2. Choreography: you trigger roughly the same thing, but via an event stream. (doesn't work as well with the request / response model of GraphQL)
3. CQRS (projections): Copies of database data, used for things like reporting. CQRS is basically "the way you read data doesn't have to be the same as the way you write it", and it allows for things like event-sourced data. If all of your data sources actually share the same database, you don't even need "projections" as much as you would just want a read replica. If you're not at enough scale to do replicas, just skip it and promise never to write data that your current domain doesn't own.

---

### What I Do

Where I work, I have gotten us to:

Queries

1. queries always start with "one database call".
2. if the "one database call" goes to one domain of data (most often true), that query goes into one service, and Federation fills in the leaves of your tree. If you really follow CQRS, this could go the same way as #3, but we don't.
3. if your "one database call" needs data from across domains (e.g. get all orders with Product X in it, but sorted by the customer's first name), you need a database projection. Preferably this can be handled by a "reporting service": it doesn't OWN any data, but it READS all data.

Mutations

1. if your top-level mutation modifies acts only within one domain, the mutation goes in a service, it can use database transactions, and Federation fills in the leaves
2. if your mutation is required to write across multiple domains and requires immediate consistency (placing an order with inventory, payments, etc), we chose orchestration to write across multiple services (and roll-back when necessary, since we don't have database transactions to do it for us).
3. if your mutation requires data from many places to send further into the request (like sending an email), we chose orchestration to pull from the multiple services and to push that data down. This feels very much like Federation, but in reverse.

Comment: Some very interesting ideas to chew on, especially the added latency. Thank your your time to put this together. I am not really sure what we would use for orchestration in our stack (nodejs/firestore).

Comment: We just have a central node.js server that makes calls to the other domain services via RPC calls (or REST).

Comment: Dan, could you elaborate on what an orchestration service would look like? I'm using a message broker (rabbitmq) with RPC pattern for cross-service communication. Some performance was sacrificed and I have yet to find a better idea